# identity, 'admin' has not been registered",

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I was able to deploy the res server in multi-user mode, imported admin indentity to the wallet as default. then I Tried to add a participant, I got this error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier 'xxxxx', has not been registered.
I have lastest composer version v0.19.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not enough detail in your question. Its likely you connected to the business network elsewhere, then tried importing the card file in the REST server from disk (ie still with the enrolment secret) but admin was already enroled (when you connected, and downloaded the cert to the card store) - you should export the admin card that you connected with (complete with cert), and discard the 'old' card file.  See this multi-user authentication tutorial -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest for an example - it couldn't be simpler.